# how to get the src from a user inputted iframe url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input function that accepts an iframe embed URL from the user is there any way to get the src from the input. For example: if user inputted `<iframe width="1263" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KWFKabzKSxw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`  i want to extract the src that would be `https://www.youtube.com/embed/KWFKabzKSxw` and assign it to a new var. My current code is attached below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function input() {
  globalThis.urlInput = "";
  urlInput = prompt("Enter embed URL:");
  if (urlInput == "") {
    alert("No URL Inputted");
  } else {
    rename();
  }
}

/*something like this but this wont work because urlInput is not an Id*/
function rename() {
  var newUrl = document.getElementById(urlInput).src;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="input()">Input1</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the input text to html using the [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) API, retrieve the `src` from it and then assign the url to a variable say, `x` like this:

```js
function input() {
  globalThis.urlInput = "";
  urlInput = prompt("Enter embed URL:");
  if (urlInput == "") {
    alert("No URL Inputted");
  } else {
    rename();
  }
}

function rename() {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const x = parser.parseFromString(urlInput, "text/html").body.firstChild.src; //convert the retrieved input text to HTML and retrieve the src attribute value from it
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="input()">Input1</button>
```

Comment: this won't work I am trying to get the src straight from the user input @AndrewL64

Comment: @anon10023108 Oh, you mean retrieve the src from the prompt? Hold on.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function input() {
  globalThis.urlInput = "";
  urlInput = prompt("Enter embed URL:");
  $('#input').html(urlInput);
  $('#input').hide();
  console.log($('#input iframe').attr('src'));
  if (urlInput == "") {
    alert("No URL Inputted");
  } else {
    rename();
  }
}

/*something like this but this wont work because urlInput is not an Id*/
function rename() {
  //var newUrl = document.getElementById(urlInput).src;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="input()">Input1</button>
<div id=input type="hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a hidden DOM and added into body and get the URL and delete the DOM after saving the src from Iframe from prompt.

```js
function input() {
  globalThis.urlInput = "";
  urlInput = prompt("Enter embed URL:");
  if (urlInput == "") {
    alert("No URL Inputted");
  } else {
    rename();
  }
}

/*something like this but this wont work because urlInput is not an Id*/
function rename() {
var input = document.createElement('div');
input.style.display = 'hidden';
input.id = 'tempInput'

document.body.appendChild(input); 
input.innerHTML = urlInput;

var URL = document.querySelector('#tempInput iframe').src;
  console.log(document.querySelector('#tempInput iframe').src);
  
  document.getElementById("tempInput").remove();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="input()">Input1</button>
```